# Build a bazel dependency inside a rule

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a macro:

```py
def py_layers(name, py_binary):
    layers = []
    # Do stuff
    some_bazel_rule(...)
    return layers
```

How can I make sure that the `py_binary` target is built by bazel before calling `some_bazel_rule`? From my understanding, looks like the proper way is to convert `py_layers` to a rule. However, it's still very unclear to me how I make `py_binary` an explicit dependency of `py_layers`. Can someone provide the correct implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You would add the `py_binary` target as a dependency of the `some_bazel_rule` target.

One thing to keep in mind is that macros just instantiate instances of rules (targets) in a repeatable way (and can perform some limited code / logic). So once the macro executes, all that's left are the targets that it generated. So it's not really that `py_layers` has dependencies, but that the targets it creates has dependencies.